# How do I create a Pass Through query with a date prompt and then load it into a local table (make table)?

Tags: ms-access, vba

How do I create a Pass Through query with a date prompt and then load it into a local table (make table)?

I want to run this in access and before it goes to the server I want the query to prompt me for a date to enter as criteria and then when the results are returned I want them stored in a local table for further processing and joining on other local tables and analyis.

I know there is a way to do this through VBA. Below is some sample code but I am not seeing the part where I can store this into a local table in MS Access.

```
/* SAMPLE CODE...not mine*/ 
Dim db As DAO.Database 
Dim qdExtData As QueryDef 
Dim strSQL As String 
Set db = CurrentDb 
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM TBL WHERE FIELD1 = " & 
[Forms]![Form1]![Combo6] 
Set qdExtData = db.CreateQueryDef("QRY_PASS_THROUGH") 
qdExtData.Connect = "ODBC;DSN=???;UID=???;PWD=???;DBQ=???;" 
qdExtData.SQL = strSQL 
qdExtData.Close 
db.Close 
Set db = Nothing 
/* SAMPLE CODE...not mine*/
```

BACKGROUND INFO: The reason I am using a Pass through query was because I copied a large amount of SQL from Peoplesoft query which includes some CASE statements and other SQL components that the Jet engine can't process but the Oracle server I am sending it to can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try

```
Dim db As DAO.Database 
Dim qdExtData As QueryDef 
Dim strSQL As String 

Set db = CurrentDb 

strSQL = "SELECT * FROM TBL WHERE FIELD1 = " & 
[Forms]![Form1]![Combo6] 

Set qdExtData = db.CreateQueryDef("QRY_PASS_THROUGH") 
qdExtData.Connect = "ODBC;DSN=???;UID=???;PWD=???;DBQ=???;" 
qdExtData.SQL = strSQL 
qdExtData.Close 

'Now use the Pass Thru query above as the data source for the Make table query below 
strSQL = "Select QRY_PASS_THROUGH.* INTO tblPassThruResults FROM QRY_PASS_THROUGH" 
db.Execute strSQL 

db.Close 
Set db = Nothing
```

However, this will work once and then you'll have to deal with deleting the previous query and table since the code above creates new ones.

A better solution is to create both the PassThruQuery and the table in development and then just reset them when you run your code:

```
Dim db As DAO.Database 
Dim qdExtData As QueryDef 
Dim strSQL As String 

Set db = CurrentDb 

strSQL = "SELECT * FROM TBL WHERE FIELD1 = " & 
[Forms]![Form1]![Combo6] 

'Reset the SQL statment for the query 
Set qdExtData = db.QueryDefs("QRY_PASS_THROUGH") 
qdExtData.SQL = strSQL 
'Empty the table 
strSQL = "DELETE * FROM tblPassThruResults"
db.Execute strSQL 

'Now use the Pass Thru query above to reload the table 
strSQL = "INSERT INTO tblPassThruResults Select QRY_PASS_THROUGH.* FROM QRY_PASS_THROUGH" 
db.Execute strSQL 

db.Close 
Set db = Nothing 
Watch out for your date string in the query. You may need to add delimiters. Top
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be to wrap the SQL in a view in the PeopleSoft system, and thereby simplify your Access code.

PeopleSoft can also generate COM API's over PeopleSoft components. This should simplify the development and also protects your external application if there is a PeopleSoft upgrade (usually very 1-2 years). The raw SQL in PeopleSoft is getting more complex; an alternativethe approach is to interact with the system via component interfaces.

There's an example on p79 of this Oracle manual:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28461_01/psft/acrobat/pt852tcpi-b0212.pdf