# open ADO recordset as visible table

Tags: mysql, ms-access, vba, odbc, ado

I'm doing something like this for the first time and it seems incredibly hard to find any useful information at all.

What I want to do:
Pass a select-query to a MySQL database and show the result in a table.

I've got that far by now: I have a button on a form and when clicked the following happens

```vb
Option Compare Database

Sub RunPassThrough(strSQL As String)

Dim ConnectionString As String
Dim Server As String
Dim User As String
Dim Pwd As String
Dim DatabaseName As String
Dim Cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim Rs As ADODB.Recordset


' Server Hostname (or IP)
Server = "192.168.178.10"

User = "user"
Pwd = "mypass"

DatabaseName = "myDB"

ConnectionString = "Provider=MSDASQL;Driver={MYSQL ODBC 5.1 DRIVER};" & _
        "Server=" & Server & ";Database=" & DatabaseName

Set Cn = New ADODB.Connection
Cn.CursorLocation = adUseClient
Cn.Mode = adModeShareDenyNone
Cn.Open ConnectionString, User, Pwd

Set Rs = New ADODB.Recordset


Rs.Open strSQL, Cn, adOpenDynamic, adLockReadOnly
'Set Rs = Cn.Execute("select * from SurveyResults limit 10;")





End Sub

Private Sub Befehl0_Click()

Dim SQL As String

SQL = "select * from SurveyResults limit 10;"

RunPassThrough (SQL)


End Sub
```

I know that `Rs.Open strSQL, Cn, adOpenDynamic, adLockReadOnly` returns an ADO recordset and I could do things with it using VBA, but all I want is to show that recorod set to the user in table.

something like OpenRecordset("Rs", as a table that the user can see)

can someone please point me into the right direction I'm going crazy...

Comment: Why not create a "normal" Pass-Through query, set its SQL (and Connection if necessary) at runtime, and open that query?

Comment: to be honest that was my first attempt and I did not get it to work either

what did work was to create a pass through query using the GUI and than modify it's sql using:

`CurrentDb.QueryDefs("myquery").SQL = "select * from SurveyResults limit 10;"` and than `DoCmd.OpenQuery ("myquery")`

but that's not really a great solution because I want the user to fill out a form that creates sql and runs it and he needs to be able to open various queries at the same time

Comment: It should work, here is an example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10988389/3820271 -- I don't think there is another way than to have actual querydef objects for each query you want to open. -- This is basically the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23664401/access-form-on-click-event-create-pass-through-query

Comment: Well, thanks to your insisting that it was the only way to do it I tried again and it turns out my only problem was that by default the "returnRecords" property of the query was set to "false" which is why I did not get the results to show...

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. My problem was simply that the ReturnsRecords Property is set to false by default.

it works now, so I'm posting a answer if anyone ever needs it.

```
Sub RunPassThrough(strSQL As String)

Dim Server As String
Dim User As String
Dim Pwd As String
Dim DatabaseName As String
Dim qdfPassThrough As DAO.QueryDef, MyDB As Database
Dim strConnect As String


' Server Hostname (or IP)
Server = "192.168.178.10"

User = "user"
Pwd = "mypass"

DatabaseName = "database"



For Each qdf In CurrentDb.QueryDefs
If qdf.Name = "PassQuery" Then
    CurrentDb.QueryDefs.Delete "PassQuery"
    Exit For
End If
Next

    strConnect = "ODBC;DRIVER={MYSQL ODBC 5.1 DRIVER};SERVER=" & Server & ";DATABASE=" & DatabaseName & ";Uid=" & User & ";Pwd=" & Pwd & ";"

    Set MyDB = CurrentDb()

    Set qdfPassThrough = MyDB.CreateQueryDef("PassQuery")


    qdfPassThrough.Connect = strConnect
    qdfPassThrough.SQL = strSQL
    qdfPassThrough.Close

    Application.RefreshDatabaseWindow
    MyDB.QueryDefs("PassQuery").ReturnsRecords = True

    DoCmd.OpenQuery "PassQuery", acViewNormal, acReadOnly
    DoCmd.Maximize


End Sub
```